# How to hide and show some elments in layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i'm trying to hide a linear layout at screen and it is some of the screen and if i use 
  android:visibility="invisible"
it take a space from the screen and i won't to be invisible and other element must show in the right sequence
is there is a method in xml to do that or in Java code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `android:visibility="gone"` or programatically `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I undestand what you're trying to do, but `invisible` will hide the element, but the element will still use up it's space. Use `gone` to completely remove the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of the element either by XML or pro-grammatically

1. **Via Program**

   TextView text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

   text.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //Completely hide from container

   or

text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   //it occupy space and view will hide

1. **Via xml**

---

andoid:visibility ="gone"

-------->